# Kernel Module not printing to dmesg until proc file is read

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to write a kernel module that will log some TCP values. Reading the output from /proc/net/tcpstat (the out of the module) is problematic as I do not want to lose info. After adding some printk to module I noticed something very strange: The printk in the init routine is fine. BUT: other printk will not print until /proc/net/tcpstat is read (using more, cat, or the like).

I really don't need /proc/net/tcpstat - just want to log some info. After reading this post I made sure that all printk messages are ending with "\n" but still it won't print to dmesg until the proc file is read.

here are a couple of print example:

```
sprintf(log_line, "%d, %d, %u, %u, %u32, %u32, %llu", destp, srcp, tp->rcv_wnd, tp->snd_wnd, data_segs_in, data_segs_out, bytes_acked);
seq_printf(seq, "%s", log_line);
printk("%s\n", log_line);
```

EDIT: init method:

```
static struct tcp_seq_afinfo tcp4_seq_afinfo = {
    .name = "tcpstat",
    .family = AF_INET,
    .seq_fops = &tcp_afinfo_seq_fops,
    .seq_ops = {
            .show = tcp_seq_show,
    },
};
```

Comment: Because you use `seq_printf`, I may assume that you have these lines in `.show` operation in `struct seq_operations`. Am I right? This function is called when the file read. This is why you got output of `printk` only at that moment.

Comment: @Tsyvarev you are right :) I added the method that mentioned the file. How can I change it? (it is my first module).

Comment: "How can I change it?" - Not sure that understand your question. If you want to print information at some other time, place `printk` invocation into the function, which is called at that time. E.g. if you want it to be called at the module's initialization stage, place `printk` into the module's init function.

Comment: There are printk in the initialization and that is fine. I want to log tcp info. currently I read from dmesg and use watch -n 0.1 cat /proc/net/tcpstat > /dev/null. I'm sure that there are more elegant ways to do it.

Comment: Normally, if something can be achieved using command line in user space, then no needs to implement that in the kernel. You write that you want to log tcp info. What do you mean by "log"? Printing the information *periodically*? Of so, create a kernel thread, which periodically prints the info.

Comment: I want to log window size, acks, etc.. I am not running my own server so I do not have access to that info.

Comment: As you able to inject into the code, where this information is available, then you should be able to create a kernel thread, which extracts the same information when you need it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I bet it's possible via eBPF and perf.

Comment: @0andriy: I did neither say nor mean that it is impossible. If you know the way, then just write an answer.